# Wcf message security with Digital Certificates

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl, iis-7.5, wcf-security

We have a WCF service hosted on server for generating bills, and our website is hosted on other server and acting as client.
We need to protect this WCF service by Digital Certificate, we want to restrict web service only between these two machines.

We purchased a certificate from **verisign authortiy**.

**Now please suggest that on which machine we should install certificate and private key and on which machine public key to secure the service.**

Comment: Was my answer useful? is there anything else you need to know?  Please be sure to mark as answer!

Answer (score 0):

Your public key goes on your server, the private key is used on the client to authenticate.

Public key is called public because it is associated with the public service that you are publishing.  Whereas a private key is used from an individual (or client) perspective.

There are several great tutorials that can help you.

[Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28248/Securing-WCF-Services-with-Certificates)

[MSDN - Message Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648360.aspx)